# Avoiding standard HTML output in ASPX page

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I'm sure this is RTFM, but I just can't figure out which FM I'm supposed to R.

I'm trying to serve a JNLP (Java Web Start) file (which is an XML format), and ASP.Net insists on appending HTML code to the response body.

More detail: I have a .aspx file and an accompanying .aspx.cs file. These were generated with the "new page" wizard. In `Page_Load()` in the .aspx.cs file, I generate some XML, do `Response.ContentType = "application/x-java-jnlp-file"`, you know the drill.

The .aspx file, however, contains:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="MyPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyProj.MyPage" EnableSessionState="False" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This code is appended to the output.

How do I avoid this? I tried calling `Response.End()` from `Page_Load()` but it's reportedly Evil and it throws nasty exceptions. `Response.Close()` is even worse, and breaks HTTP. I also tried simply removing all the HTML from the body, but ASP then complains about the fact that it needs a `<head runat="server">` for something called "Themed CSS" (I'm not sure what that means).

Any leads?

Thanks!

Comment: Am I missing something, or would this be a great time to use a [Handler](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx)?

Comment: +1: This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear and the first line made me chuckle :)

Comment: Have you considered creating a custom handler (ashx) that outputs xml based on a template?  If the template is fairly complex, you could use a T4 template or xslt to generate the required xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off themes by adding EnableTheming="false" and Theme="" to Page directive

So your page would become

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="MyPage.aspx.cs" 
         Inherits="MyProj.MyPage" EnableSessionState="False" 
         EnableTheming="false" Theme=""%>
```

Adding a Response.Clear() before any output should then work as expected. However Brad's comment is spot on, this is perfect for an [HTTP Handler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001)

Comment: Marked this one as the answer because it's become my quickfix. I see how handlers would've been the true answer, though. Thanks all!

Answer (score 4):

Obligatory [Use a Handler](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx).

This gives you all the control necessary over the direct-output of information. The article included even gives an example of outputting an image.

Comment: This is the best way of serving content that is non-html.  Whether HTML, images, files, etc.  It's fast, lightweight (doesn't have the full page lifecycle) and you have complete and utter control over what bits go back to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Just have the page as :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="MyPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyProj.MyPage" EnableSessionState="False" %>
```

Delete the rest of the HTML in the page and as the poster suggested and do a Response.Clear()..

It is **important** you delete everything after the end of the

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="MyPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyProj.MyPage" EnableSessionState="False" %> declaration.
```

Answer (score 0):

With a `Response.Clear()` or just remove it from the page!

Comment: Removing it from the page does not work, as explained in the question. But, when to call Response.Clear()? Not in Page_Load(), I assume, since that appears to be called *before* the HTML in the .aspx is rendered.

Comment: Well, thanks to your response I tried a bit harder to "just remove it from the page!" Turns out adding `EnableTheming="False" StylesheetTheme="" Theme=""` to the `Page` directive does the trick (in my case). Thanks :-) (I had only done `EnableTheming="False"` first, which apparently is not good enough)